# New Order Product addon details in admin email-php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

when I receive an new order email from a client in woocommerce the add on product details are not included in the new order email I receive as an admin. I am looking for addon form to show details for the person processing the order. Please help with a solution to edit php email template!!

I found a php snippet but dont know enough php to know where to put it and in what order. The snippet I found is this Please help it would be much appreciated.

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
// Existing code to display product name, quantity, price, etc.

```
// Add our snippet here to display Product Add-On information
$addon_data = maybe_unserialize( wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_wc_pao_order_item_data' ) );

if ( ! empty( $addon_data ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $addon_data as $addon ) {
        echo '<li>' . esc_html( $addon['name'] ) . ': ' . esc_html( $addon['value'] ) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

}